# Python3 tkinter.Canvas.move() method makes artifacts on screen

Tags: python, tkinter, python-3.5, tkinter-canvas, artifacts

I'm trying to execute the code found in one of the Stackoverflow answers. It's a single window application with 2 circles which can be moved with the mouse.
When I move circles - I see artifacts. See [Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tnjNG.png)

Program code:

```
import tkinter as tk

TOKENWIDTH = 10

class Example(tk.Frame):
    '''Illustrate how to drag items on a Tkinter canvas'''

    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        # create a canvas
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(width=400, height=400, bg="white")
        self.canvas.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

        # this data is used to keep track of an
        # item being dragged
        self._drag_data = {"x": 0, "y": 0, "item": None}

        # create a couple of movable objects
        self._create_token((100, 100), "red")
        self._create_token((200, 100), "black")

        # add bindings for clicking, dragging and releasing over
        # any object with the "token" tag
        self.canvas.tag_bind("token", "<ButtonPress-1>", self.on_token_press)
        self.canvas.tag_bind("token", "<ButtonRelease-1>", self.on_token_release)
        self.canvas.tag_bind("token", "<B1-Motion>", self.on_token_motion)

    def _create_token(self, coord, color):
        '''Create a token at the given coordinate in the given color'''
        (x,y) = coord
        self.canvas.create_oval(x-25, y-25, x+25, y+25,
                                outline="blue", fill=color, tags="token", width = TOKENWIDTH)

    def on_token_press(self, event):
        '''Begining drag of an object'''
        # record the item and its location
        self._drag_data["item"] = self.canvas.find_closest(event.x, event.y)[0]
        self._drag_data["x"] = event.x
        self._drag_data["y"] = event.y
        self.canvas.update_idletasks()

    def on_token_release(self, event):
        '''End drag of an object'''
        # reset the drag information
        self._drag_data["item"] = None
        self._drag_data["x"] = 0
        self._drag_data["y"] = 0
        self.canvas.update_idletasks()

    def on_token_motion(self, event):
        '''Handle dragging of an object'''
        # compute how much the mouse has moved
        delta_x = event.x - self._drag_data["x"]
        delta_y = event.y - self._drag_data["y"]
        # move the object the appropriate amount
        self.canvas.move(self._drag_data["item"], delta_x, delta_y)
        # record the new position
        self._drag_data["x"] = event.x
        self._drag_data["y"] = event.y
        self.canvas.update_idletasks()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    Example(root).pack(fill="both", expand=True)
    root.mainloop()
```

The code has TOKENWIDTH which is used in standard Canvas.create_oval() method.

I experimented a bit and found that When TOKENWIDTH is set to 6 or more, the code produces artifacts on Canvas when moving object. If TOKENWIDTH is within 1..5 everything works great.

The following line of code doesn't help:

> self.canvas.update_idletasks()

How this issues can be fixed? Any ideas?
As a workaround I think about putting two circles of different color one on another to make a round "border" effect.

Comment: I tried various values for `TOKENWIDTH` but I don't get any artifacts on Python 3.6.0, running on a Debian derivative Linux with the KDE window manager. What OS are you using? And how are you running this script? Are you running it directly from a shell, or from with an IDE?

Comment: I don't see any artifacts on OSX either. BTW, the calls to `update_idletasks()` can be removed. They are completely unnecessary in this context.

Comment: @PM2Ring  I see the artifacts on Win10, 3.6.1 and suspect Dmitry is also.  I strongly suspect that this is a Windows-specific bug in the circle drawing algorithm.  (Whether in tk or the Windows graphics primitive, I have no idea.)  The dots come from the last 1-pixel projections on the right edge not being properly erased when the horizontal component of the motion is to the left ( deltax is negative).  With the token still, the rightmost column of pixels is not centered on the horizontal axis, like it should be (unlike the left edge).  Asymmetry and dots disappear when width is 5.

Comment: To put the canvas on the frame rather than the root window, add `self` as the first argument in the Canvas call.

Comment: I can see the artifacts on Windows 7, 3.6.1 too. They seem to only appear when moving the mouse to the left, and moving the token back over the artifacts (when not going left) removes them.

When you change `TOKENWIDTH` (The width of the outline of the circles) to 7 or below for me, the artifacts disappear. When it is 8+, the artifacts are visible.

I suspect this is an issue to do with the outline of an object when moved , with some pixels remaining there, on Windows at least.

So for the mean time, try reducing `TOKENWIDTH`.

Comment: I'm running Windows 10, Python 3.5.2. @Terry Jan Reedy is right. Artifacts only happen when there's "left" component of the movement.