# Tkinter canvas move leaves a pixel trail

Tags: python, canvas, tkinter

I'm working on a game in a Tkinter canvas where points move around the screen. I place each point at a location with `tkinter.Canvas.create_oval(...)` and subsequently move the points with `tkinter.Canvas.move(pointID,delta_x,delta_y)`.

My problem is that the points seem to leave a trail behind when they are moved. I made a simplified example that demonstrates my problem.

```
from tkinter import Canvas,mainloop,Tk
import numpy as np
import random
import traceback
import threading
import time
from queue import Queue

class Point:
    def __init__(self,the_canvas,uID):
        self.uID = uID
        self.location = np.ones((2)) * 200
        self.color = "#"+"".join([random.choice('0123456789ABCDEF') for j in range(6)])
        self.the_canvas = the_canvas
        self.the_canvas.create_oval(200,200,200,200,
                     fill=self.color,outline=self.color,width=6,
                     tags=('runner'+str(self.uID),'runner'))
    def move(self):
        delta = (np.random.random((2))-.5)*20
        self.the_canvas.move('runner'+str(self.uID),delta[0],delta[1])

def queue_func():
    while True:
        time.sleep(.25)
        try:
            next_action = the_queue.get(False)
            next_action()
        except Exception as e: 
            if str(e) != "": 
                print(traceback.format_exc())

the_queue = Queue()
the_thread = threading.Thread(target=queue_func)
the_thread.daemon = True
the_thread.start()

window = Tk()
window.geometry('400x400')
the_canvas = Canvas(window,width=400,height=400,background='black')
the_canvas.grid(row=0,column=0)

points = {}
for i in range(100):
    points[i] = Point(the_canvas,i)

def random_movement():
    while True:
        for point in points.values():
            point.move()

the_queue.put(random_movement)

mainloop()
```

And the result is something like this:

[image: example1]

I need to be able to move Points around cleanly, without leaving anything behind.

- I tried changing the `move()` function so that each point is deleted according to its tag and redrawn at the new location, but that results in the same problem.
- I have tried `fill=''` and also `outline=''` in the `Canvas.oval` config, but this does not help.
- The behavior of these pixel trials seem erratic, like they will disappear over time, only leaving a limited amount of footprints behind.
- I have tried removing the `time.sleep(.2)` from the movement loop, and that seems to make the problem a lot more pronounced.

[image: example2]

- I've found that the only way to cleanup these rogue colored pixels is to run `canvas.delete("all")`, so as of now, my only solution is to delete everything and redraw everything constantly. That doesn't seem like a great solution to me.

What's a good way to avoid these "pixel trails"? It really just seems like a bug to me, but maybe I'm making a blunder somewhere.

Comment: FWIW, I can't duplicate this problem on my Mac. I don't see any of the artifacts that are in your screenshots. It may have something to do with your use of threading -- tkinter sometimes has difficulty with threading. Unless you're trying to move tens of thousands of points, I don't think you need all of the overhead of threading.

Comment: @BryanOakley FWIW I am able to reproduce it on my Windows 7 Machine, but I am also of the opinion the threading is the main issue, though even after removing the threading I did notice there was very minimal ghosting on one of the runs.

Comment: Same results. The artifacting does mostly go away when you remove threading and use an `after()` loop instead. However there is still some artifacting.

Comment: It appears the issue may be related to the borders on the oval in windows at least. I tested it by removing the borders and all artifacting is gone.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After some digging I found this post here: [Python3 tkinter.Canvas.move() method makes artifacts on screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44346738/python3-tkinter-canvas-move-method-makes-artifacts-on-screen)

The problem there was the borders of the oval. So what I did was remove the borders and make the oval slightly larger to compensate and it looks like that did the trick.

If you change this line:

```
self.the_canvas.create_oval(200, 200, 200, 200, 
                            fill=self.color, outline=self.color, width=6,
                            tags=('runner' + str(self.uID), 'runner'))
```

To this:

```
self.the_canvas.create_oval(200,200,206,206,
                            fill=self.color,outline='', width=0,
                            tags=('runner'+str(self.uID),'runner'))
```

the problem should go away with or without threading.

If you would like to see what your code would look like without threading here is an example:

```
import tkinter as tk
import numpy as np
import random


class Point:
    def __init__(self, the_canvas, uID):
        self.uID = uID
        self.location = np.ones((2)) * 200
        self.color = "#"+"".join([random.choice('0123456789ABCDEF') for j in range(6)])
        self.the_canvas = the_canvas
        self.the_canvas.create_oval(200, 200, 206, 206,
                                    fill=self.color, outline='', width=0,
                                    tags=('runner'+str(self.uID), 'runner'))

    def move(self):
        delta = (np.random.random((2))-.5)*20

        self.the_canvas.move('runner'+str(self.uID), delta[0], delta[1])

window = tk.Tk()
window.geometry('400x400')
the_canvas = tk.Canvas(window, width=400, height=400, background='black')
the_canvas.grid(row=0, column=0)

points = {}
for i in range(100):
    points[i] = Point(the_canvas, i)

def random_movement():
    for point in points.values():
        point.move()
    window.after(50, random_movement)

random_movement()
window.mainloop()
```

Results:

[image]

Comment: @Idlehands I did miss the `window.mainloop()` when pasting my code thanks.

Comment: Aaah no sorry I was somewhat confused, because I had it as `window.after(25, random_movement); window.mainloop()` and was trying to figure out for the longest time why `random_movement()` wasn't drawing anything real time.  The recursive `after()` call was what I missed.  Felt like a dunce.

Comment: @Idlehands lol. It happens. I have been known to miss a few obvious things and only find out later from someone pointing it out.

Answer (score 3):

Weirdly enough the issue seems to be coming from
`width=6` in `create_oval()`
getting rid of it seems to resolve the issue.
The way you've originally setup your `create_oval()` is making an oval of zero area (i.e. non-existent) and border width of 6... which is obviously a troubelsom combination.

So here's the new code, with some extra modfications:

```
from tkinter import Canvas,mainloop,Tk
import numpy as np
import random
import traceback
import time

class Point:
    def __init__(self,uID):
        self.uID = uID
        self.location = np.ones((2)) * 200
        self.color = "#" + "".join([random.choice('0123456789ABCDEF') for j in range(6)])

    def move(self):
        delta = (np.random.random((2)) - .5) * 20
        self.location += delta

    def draw(self,canv):
        x0, y0 = self.location
        canv.create_oval(
             x0, y0, x0 + 2, y0 + 2,
             fill=self.color, outline=self.color,
             tags=('runner'+str(self.uID),'runner')
        )

def repeater(window):
    the_canvas.delete('all')
    for i in points:
        i.move()
        i.draw(the_canvas)
    window.after(25, repeater, window)

window = Tk()
window.geometry('400x400')
the_canvas = Canvas(window,width=400,height=400,background='black')
the_canvas.grid(row=0,column=0)

points = []
for i in range(100):
    points.append(Point(i))

repeater(window)
window.mainloop()
```

Also, btw, deleting all elements on the canvas is the way to clear it. it's not wasteful since you're updating all elements on it anyway.

Comment: Yes the issue is related to the border. However it is probably best to set color to nothing and width to zero. This should prevent any chance of artifacting in windows. The reason I say to set `width=0` rather than removing it all together is that width defaults to size of 1 if you do not have it defined.

Comment: it's probably okay as long as the width isn't larger than the object (i.e.oval) itself?